# Latest OSX Java update (7u55) appears to break rotated text for applets

Tags: java, macos, applet, rotation

Our applet draws rotated text using AffineTransform, a method that we adopted to overcome previous problems with rotated text on OSX (discussed here:
[Java rotated text has reversed characters sequence](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14569475/java-rotated-text-has-reversed-characters-sequence))

It worked until last thursday when I finally broke down and installed the latest OSX update. This brought me to "Java v7 update 55", and now the rotated text doesn't work anymore, but *in the applet only*. It works in the standalone. I'm using code like

```
AffineTransform rot = AffineTransform.getRotateInstance(rotAngle*Math.PI/180);
Font fRot = g.getFont().deriveFont(rot);
g.setFont(fRot);
g.drawString(p.displayName,stringX,stringY);
```

It's rotating the characters correctly, but it doesn't position them correctly for strings longer than 1 character.